# Implementing scalar MIB objects in PySNMP not work

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm download example from:

http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/twisted/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html

And try to run:

snmpwalk -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6

Get:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "implementing-scalar-mib-objects1.py", line 81, in <module>
    reactor.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1261, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1270, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 896, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/carrier/base.py", line 70, in _cbFun
    self, transportDomain, transportAddress, incomingMessage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/entity/engine.py", line 152, in __receiveMessageCbFun
    self, transportDomain, transportAddress, wholeMsg
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/proto/rfc3412.py", line 433, in receiveMessage
    PDU, maxSizeResponseScopedPDU, stateReference)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/cmdrsp.py", line 150, in processPdu
    self.handleMgmtOperation(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextName, PDU)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/cmdrsp.py", line 293, in handleMgmtOperation
    rspVarBinds = mgmtFun(*varBinds, **context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/smi/instrum.py", line 261, in readNextVars
    return self.flipFlopFsm(self.fsmReadNextVar, *varBinds, **context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/smi/instrum.py", line 227, in flipFlopFsm
    rval = mgmtFun((tuple(name), val), **context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py", line 527, in readGetNext
    return node.readGetNext((nextName, val), **context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py", line 660, in readGetNext
    return MibTree.readGetNext(self, varBind, **context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py", line 527, in readGetNext
    return node.readGetNext((nextName, val), **context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py", line 780, in readGetNext
    return self.readGet(varBind, **context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py", line 761, in readGet
    return self.name, self.getValue(name, **context)
exceptions.TypeError: getValue() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cbCtx'
```

In v1 i'm get empty answer:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6
End of MIB
```

python3-pysnmp4 4.4.6-1 on Debian testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback comes from Python 2.7 while you refer to python3-pysnmp-4.4.6. Please make sure you are using pysnmp version which is compatible with the examples.

As a side note, the [example script](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/twisted/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#implementing-scalar-mib-objects) you are running will not respond to SNMP v1 queries unless you add:

```
 config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 1, 'my-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 3, 6, 5))
```

call to it.

Comment: Not work too. python3 implementing-scalar-mib-objects1.py 
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 878, in runUntilCurrent
... builtins.TypeError: getValue() got an unexpected keyword argument 'snmpEngine'

Comment: But work fine with pysnmp 4.4.5 installed by pip3. Is it bug in 4.4.6?